# Showing that a subring is a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Say we have a commutative, unitary ring $R$. We take a subset $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ of $R$ and generate a ring $R^{'}=\mathbb{Z}[x_i|i \in I]$ inside $R$. Let $S=\mathbb{Z}[X_i|i \in I]$. Then we have that $R^{'}=S/J$ for some ideal $J$ of $S$. Let $K$ be a possibly infinite index set. Now say that we claim that $J=(f_k|k \in K)$. I am not entirely sure what I have to show to prove that claim. I think I need to show two things. First, take $x \in (f_k|k \in K)$. That is $x=\displaystyle\sum_{k \in K}g_kf_k$ where $g_k \in S$ with $g_k=0$ for all but finitely many $k$. Then show that $x+J=J$ and so $x \in J$. Second, take $x^{'} \in J \subseteq S$ and show that $x^{'}=\displaystyle \sum_{k \in K} g_kf_k$ for some $g_k \in S$. Then $x^{'} \in (f_k|k \in K)$. Is this the correct logic here?

Comment: Isn't any ideal of S generated by some polynomials? I have no idea what you claim and want to show.

Comment: I claim that I know what $J$ is. My question is what do I need to do show to prove that $J$ is what I think it is.

Comment: but what are the $f_k$? if you are allowed to have $K$ and the $f_k$ be whatever you want, then you can just take $K=J$ and let the $f_k$ be the elements of $J$. (ie, for $x\in J$, let $f_x=x$.)

Comment: $f_k$ are some elements of $S$. In a concrete example I’m doing I know them explicitly and I want to show that the ideal generated by them is in fact $J$.

Comment: Isn't then better to replace this general question to that concrete example?

Comment: I sort of was looking for a general strategy in this sort of questions

Comment: @amator2357 ah! if you are just looking for a general strategy, then yes, what you've written is a correct approach. :) (one small point: recall that, when you're working with the sum $\sum_{k\in K}g_k f_k$, only *finitely many* of the $g_k$ can be non-zero, even if $K$ is infinite)

Comment: @Atticus Stonestrom Great! Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure!! :)